# I have installed XAMPP and PHPmailer in ubuntu 20.04 but mailer not working

Tags: xampp, phpmailer

I have installed XAMPP and PHPmailer on UBUNTU 20.04 but when I run a bulkmail.php script the error shown as

"**Warning: require(class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bulkmail.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bulkmail.php on line 2**

Please help.

Comment: That means the file Is not in any of the Directories in your include_path, so either add the directory to the include path, or move the files. You’re also using a very old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: could you please guide me in detail. I have installed phpmailer through command line. Thank you

Comment: I tried by installing LAMP but there it is giving error as localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Read pretty much *any* guide on debugging PHP for how to approach this. It’s not a PHPMailer problem.